# Play multiple URL at once in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

How to play multiple URLs sequentially in android? I have a small streaming url 10s/each of one complete song. I need to play it one after another. Is there any way doing it so the music don't get lagged?

Comment: try doing it using AsyncTask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the m3u8 playlist to play with MediaPlayer. However, you wouldn't able to do it. You can use ExoPlayer to play m3u8 list. Check this link 
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

Answer (score 3):

https://exoplayer.dev/media-sources.html read Advanced composition

```
MediaSource firstSource =
        new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(...).createMediaSource(firstVideoUri);
    MediaSource secondSource =
        new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(...).createMediaSource(secondVideoUri);
    // Plays the first video twice, then the second video.
    ConcatenatingMediaSource concatenatedSource =
        new ConcatenatingMediaSource(firstSource, firstSource, secondSource);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
simpleExoPlayerView.setShowMultiWindowTimeBar(true);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question.